# Cocoapods "No such module <pod>"

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm new to Cocoapods:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
```

`use_frameworks!
pod 'ReachabilitySwift', git: 'https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift'`

My podfile has this lines and 3 targets. And I'm trying to do:
import ReachabilitySwift and error "No such module 'ReachabilitySwift'" comes.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CocoaPods `1.0.0` then you need to explicitly set the target:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

target '<Name matching XCode target>' do
  pod 'ReachabilitySwift', git: 'https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

pod 'ReachabilitySwift', git: 'https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift'
```

You have to give the source of Cocoapods

Comment: This error keeps on showing also when "pod install"

Comment: [!] The `Project [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Project/Pods-Project.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

Comment: And "No such module ..." keeps appearing

Comment: sorry try pod install --verbose

Comment: Follow the link to install pods in your project... https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#commands

Comment: @JoãoCorreia please paste your pod file